# Конечные точки WCF службы

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Сейчас я занимаю изучением WCF служб и у меня возникли некоторые вопросы касательно конечных точек.

Я правильно понимаю, что с помощью конечных точек можно разделить функциональность таким образом, что бы к определенному контракту было обращение по своему адресу?

Допустим у меня 2 интерфейса(Допустим `IContract1` и `IContract2`) и в каждый описывает контракт. Если я хочу сделать так, что бы в рамках одного сервиса у меня было обращение к 2 ум конечным точкам, каждая из которых предоставляет услуги своего контракта, то я должен описать сервис, как

```
class ServiceName : IContract1, IContract2
```

?
Или можно так:

```
class ServiceName
{
    class Contract1: IContract1
    {}
    class Contract2: IContract2
}
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я правильно понимаю, что с помощью конечных точек можно разделить
>   функциональность таким образом, что бы к определенному контракту было
>   обращение по своему адресу?

Да, все правильно. Каждая конечная точка описывается 3 параметрами

- контракт(contract)
- адрес(address)
- привязка(binding)

Поэтому, вы можете у одного сервиса сконфигурировать каждую конечную точку,устанавливая различные значения параметрам.
 
Например, возможно, что две конечный точки одного сервиса будут доступны по разным транспортным протоколам, например, одна по http(`binding="basicHttpBinding"`), другая по tcp(`binding="netTcpBinding"`)

Класс сервиса должен реализовывать интерфейсы контрактов сервиса. То есть правильный вариант объявления класса будет такой

```
class ServiceName
   :IContract1
   ,IContract2
```

**Edit**: Для каждой конечной точки вы должны создать своего клиента

```
public class Contract1ProxyClient
    : ClientBase<IContract1>
    , IContract1
{
    public Contract1ProxyClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
        : base(binding, remoteAddress)
    { }

    public Contract1ProxyClient(string endpointConfigurationName)
        : base(endpointConfigurationName)
    { }
}

public class Contraсt2ProxyClient
    : ClientBase<IContract2>
    , IContract2
{
    public Contract2ProxyClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
        : base(binding, remoteAddress)
    { }

    public Contract2ProxyClient(string endpointConfigurationName)
        : base(endpointConfigurationName)
    { }
}
```

На счет количества контрактов, реализуемых сервисом. Строго правила нет, вы архитектор, вам решать. Но, по-моему IMHO, здесь должна быть золотая середина.

- Если у сервиса много контрактов, то класс сервиса становится тяжелее
  отлаживать, тяжелее править.
- Чем больше контрактов реализует сервис, тем больше вероятность того,
  что в него нужно будет вносить изменения.
- Если за каждую реализацию контракта в сервисе отвечает свой
  программист, когда сервис правит несколько программистов. В таком
  случае лучше декомпозировать сервис на несколько сервисов.

Поэтому, старайтесь объединять контракты сервисов по предметной области.

Comment: Соответственно для каждой точки будет сгенерирован свой клиент? И еще у меня есть вопрос по правилу хорошего тона: Допустим есть N, контрактов, которые работают с данными(Имеют общую предметную область). Является ли хорошим тоном запихать эти N контрактов в один класс, например DataHelperService и сделать N конечных точек или существует какой-то общепринятый предел?

Comment: @iluxa, обновил ответ.

Comment: @iluxa, обновил ответ